# Connecting email client to address on old server

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, web-hosting

I am planning on moving my client's web & email hosting to a different company (their current one is too unreliable).

To handle their email, my plan is to:

1. Register account with new hosting company
2. Point domain to new server
3. Create new account in Thunderbird for the **old server**
4. Create another account in Thunderbird for the **new server**
5. Drag & drop email from the old account to the new account

My problem is how do I link Thunderbird to the email account on the old server?

All I can see for my own email account (a Gmail account) is the following:

[image]

Would I just need to update `Server Name` with a value provided to me by the old hosting company?

Comment: How do you "point domain to new server" in step 2? The two most common ways interpret it either only affect incoming mail, or don't affect mail at all.

Comment: Gmail is hosted by Google. The actual server is way beyond your reach.

Comment: Since this is a system administration issue, you may find an answer by searching on the Q&A site for system administration https://serverfault.com/